# Vegetation relative abundance stacked bar plot, grouped by site

Tags: r, group-by, vegan, stacked-bar-chart

I have a vegetation dataset, with type of vegetation, species, and occurrence (by site- in relative abundance). I have been trying to create a stacked bar plot. This is my dataset, any help would be much appreciated!!!

I have tried:

1.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(fill=type, y=S1N2, x=type)) + 
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

2. 

```
mat.dat<- as.matrix(dat)
example_NMDS=metaMDS(mat.dat, # Our community-by-species matrix
                k=1)
plot(example_NMDS)
ordiplot(example_NMDS,type="n") #Ordination plot function especially for congested plots
orditorp(example_NMDS,display="species",col="red") #The function adds text or points to              ordination plots
orditorp(example_NMDS,display="sites",cex=1.25,air=0.01)
```

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be specific about non-base packages, where are `ordiplot`/`orditorp` defined?), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.